# Asp.Net WebAPI and AttributeRouting - no overloaded attribute constructor?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have just downloaded AttributeRouting NuGet package for WebAPI and having a problem within my controller.
I thought the way to use it was to have something like:

```
 public class InboxController : ApiController
    {
        private IInboxService _inboxService;

        public InboxController(IInboxService inboxService)
        {
            _inboxService = inboxService;            
        }

        public IEnumerable<MessageModel> GetAll()
        {
            return _inboxService.GetAllMessages();
        }

      [HttpGet("Inbox/Count")]
            public int GetInboxCount()
            {
                return _inboxService.GetMessageCount();
            }
}
```

However I get the following error:
Error   2   'System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

I need to get this up and running fairly quickly. Is there any reason why the HttpGet attribute doesn't have an overloaded constructor?

**UPDATE**

```
    [GET("Inbox/EnquiryCount")]
    public EnquiryCountModel GetEnquiryCounts()
    {
        var model = new EnquiryCountModel();
        model.EnquiryCount = _inboxService.GetCustomerEnquiriesCount();
        model.EnquiryResponseCount = _inboxService.GetCustomerEnquiryResponseCount();
        return model;
    }
```

**In routes:**

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("InboxEnquiryApi", "api/inbox/{action}", new { Controller = "Inbox" }, null, new WebApiAuthenticationHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

When I hit the URL at 'api/inbox/EnquiryCount' I get the this error:

```
**No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49597/api/inbox/enquirycount'**
```

Comment: It's GETAttribute instead of HttpGet

Comment: GetAttribute is not resolved when compiled, are you sure?

Comment: Yup, GETAttribute. Add using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;

Comment: GET works of course;) but am now getting multiple Multiple Actions Were Found that match the request error. I thought this was the whole point of this library. Can they not be mixed?

Comment: You need to understand how the ASP.NET Web API routing works internally. It works with url as a resource in mind. AttributeRouting just add a route, similar to global.asax routes. It cannot change the underlying engine. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions

Comment: Added update above. I don't understand if I've added the route by both using the attribute and allowing the route in the bootstrappper, why its now not resolving. I might have to move the /enquirycount into its own controller which I've already done with many of my routes. Shame as I've got lots of very small controllers which are just specialisations of the same sort of controller.  I thought this would be a little easier to set-up.

Comment: miising api, [GET("**api**/Inbox/EnquiryCount")]. It will be more better if your read routing throughly

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is I don't understand where default routing ends and how AttributeRouting is supposed to work together with routing/where they overlap.  I've modified the routing line (with api/), but I still have issues.

Comment: I am repeating,  It will be more better if your read routing thoroughly, routing works from top to bottom fashion. First match win. Attribute routing just embed routes in RouteTable.Routes collection

Comment: @jaffa, Short answer is 'do not mix them--think of AttributeRouting as an alternative to MapHttpRoute'.  Long answer is "If I understand the author's documentation, a future release will allow you to declare an a routing handler. One use of that would be to mix mapping and attribution."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute routing is supported in Web api 2

Here is the details: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 6):

This syntax has been changed in newer versions of the webapi. The [HTTPPOST] is now standalone and there is a new attribute for the route aptly name ROUTE which takes the route url
eg.

[Route("GetRes/{month}")]